# PDF stream works on Chrome, but not IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I'm streaming a dynamically generated PDF from the server to the frontend. The PDF will display with no issues in Chrome, but generates this error in IE11.

> DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "!DOCTYPE
>   html"

The PDF is dynamically generated and returns a GUID on success which is then used in the AJAX success to open a link to the new PDF.

On the front end:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "myURL",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            data: The data used to create the PDF on the server,
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = "newURL?fileIdentifier=" + result;
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
```

On the code behind:

```
var pdfFilePath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.pdf", tempWorkPlanDirectory, fileIdentifier);

            var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFilePath);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + ".pdf\"");
            Response.OutputStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
```

Comment: Did you try adding a doctype? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible since it's a blob object.